# Fall-through in Python dictionary replacement of switch/case

Tags: python, switch-statement, fall-through

I try to implement switch/case mechanism in Python. After reading several websites and questions here (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python)), I built the code below. But it behaves wrong, having what I understand to be - a fall-through, which can be even [problematic to get](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/3fq3ak/how_to_do_a_switchcase_fallthrough/), surely not a default expected result.

```
def something():
    print 'something'

def somethingElse():
    print 'something else'

def switch():
    cases = {
        0: something(),
        1: something(),
        2: something(),
        3: something(),
        4: something(),
        5: something()
        }

    cases.get(2, somethingElse())

switch()
```

(Obviously the same switch for every case is just for the sake of the example)

When I run it I expect `something()` to be run only once (as I manually input `2`). However, the output in the console is:

```
something
something
something
something
something
something
something else
```

What means it was run 6 times plus the default value run. I cannot understand what in this code allows for such a fall-through? Or maybe the problem is different?

This is Python 2.7.12 here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dictionary is calling every single function when it creates the cases. Your functions print (a side effect) rather than return a string so you see all of the strings printed to console.

Instead, your switch should return a function and then you can call that function.

```
def something():
    print 'something'

def somethingElse():
    print 'something else'

def switch():
    cases = {
        0: something,
        1: something,
        2: something,
        3: something,
        4: something,
        5: something
        }

    # All of the values in `cases` are functions so it is safe
    # to call whatever `cases.get(...)` returns.
    cases.get(2, somethingElse)()

switch()
```

Comment: Thank you, the mistake was obviously in the place where `()` should be to run a function. Thanks for your side comments as well, I will correct those.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return function name and then call it. Like this

```
def something():
    print ('something')

def somethingElse():
    print ('something else')

cases = {1: something, 2: something, 3:something, 4:something,5:something}
result = cases.get(2, somethingElse)()
```

~

Comment: Thank you, you are correct, but I guess @supersam654 was faster!